# Loop only prints one value into to my file.txt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase loop prints only one value into my file.txt, I need all values. Does anyone does know why?

```
booksRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        var books = userSnapshot.val();
        var book = 'book:';
        book +=  '\r';
        book += books.title;
        book +=  '\r';
        book += books.author;

        let blob = new Blob([book], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })
        saveAs(blob, 'file.txt');
    });
});
```

Comment: You're saving the file within the loop, hence the value of the last round only is saved. Save the blob outside of the loop.

Comment: when a put the blob outside the loop, i get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: book is not defined"

can you put an example how to do it, maybe a do it wrong?

Comment: You've to declare `book` in that same scope. Also you need to remove the line which empties `book` from the body of the loop.

Comment: where and how exactly?

Comment: line which empties book? i don't have any empty line from book, i am very confused right now :) i am sorry

Comment: Hmm.. poor wording from me, you're initializing `book` within the loop, that can be done only once before the loop.

Comment: for loop block {
code that push array of data}
save array to file 
Just like @Teemu said save method should be outside of loop block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save your file after each book is read which is not necessarily good practice since with a large number of books it will take some time and it may happen that file with all books will be overwritten by a Blob from the previous time.

The root cause, however, is the line where you define books string. You should do it line before for each loop, otherwise, it gets reset on every iteration.

Following code uses string interpolation, arrow functions and `const` declarations and is an example implementation of what you want to achieve.

```
// Stringify books.    
booksRef.once('value').then(booksSnapshot => {
  // Initialise books before the loop below.
  let books = '';
  // Iterate over each book in books
  booksSnapshot.forEach(bookSnapshot => {
    // Get value of the snapshot
    const book = bookSnapshot.val();
    // Compose an entry.
    books += `book:\n\t${book.title}\n\t${book.author}`;
  });

  const blob = new Blob([books], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
  saveAs(blob, 'file.txt');
});
```

Results in:

```
book:
  Don Quixote
  Miguel de Cervantes.
book:
  In Search of Lost Time
  Marcel Proust
```

Comment: i got an syntax error... 

    151 |     const book = bookSnapshot.val();
  152 |     // Compose an entry.
> 153 |     books += `book:\n\t${book.title}\n\t${book.author}`;
      |     ^
  154 |   });
  155 | 
  156 |   const blob = new Blob([book], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });

Comment: my error is in this line:
    `> 153 |     books += `book:\n\t${book.title}\n\t${book.author}`;`

Comment: i have changed all const into let but it still gives me an syntax error.